# Filtering a list based on a second list

Tags: python, filter, list-comprehension

Here is what is probably a simple question, but I wasn't able to find a straightforward answer for on my own.

Given two lists, one with only a list of ids, the other with all data, including some ids that we don't care about:

`all_data = [['abc', 123], ['cde', 234], ['fgh', 345]]`

 `ids  = ['abc', 'fgh']`

what is the best way to get the following output, note that it keeps only those that have the same ids:
`new_data = [['abc', 123], ['fgh', 345]]`

My current code does something like:

```
for x in all_data:
    for y in ids:
         if x[0] == y:
              new_data.append(x)
```

What woud you do differently? Is there a built-in function that takes care of this that I missed somewhere?

(I say "something like" because it's actually a very long sequence involving sets and all that which is why there is not "pythonic" one-liner to share.)

UPDATE:
Well you guys are fun.

How about I make it a little harder. What if instead of "all_data" I have a a dictionary all_data_dict that has several list entries of the same format as "all_data"? Following the rules, I'll make sure to accept the answer to the original question, but if you all want to keep up with the fun, let's see what we get!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

being that many have used dicts or LC I thought I should show `filter`

```
>>> all_data = [['abc', 123], ['cde', 234], ['fgh', 345]]    
>>> ids = set(['abc', 'fgh'])
>>> values = filter(lambda value: value[0] in ids, all_data)
>>> values
[['abc', 123], ['fgh', 345]]
>>>
```

as for the second part.

```
>>> all_data_dict = {'abc':all_data, 'cde':all_data, 'fgh':all_data}
>>> ids = set(['abc', 'fgh'])
>>> dict(filter(lambda value: value[0] in ids, all_data_dict.items()))
{'abc': [['abc', 123], ['cde', 234], ['fgh', 345]], 'fgh': [['abc', 123], ['cde', 234], ['fgh', 345]]}
```

Comment: You can use `in` directly: `lambda value: value[0] in ids`.

Comment: Not thinking about efficiency, this is my favourite answer: `filter` is self documenting, you only need to read the line once to understand what the programmer wanted to do (which is to filter).

Comment: yep, I thinks its pretty efficient, since we are not creating any dicts the check is constant, filter applies a linear search.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it's very efficient. What I meant was that even if efficiency wasn't important (small sets etc.) it's still my favourite - words are better than constructs, constructs are better than loops.

Comment: Definitely chosen for using filter as a "built-in" is what I was looking for. Plus, no for loops.

Comment: I actually find the list comprehension more readable than `filter` here, [Guido agrees](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196).  Especially in the case of needing a lambda for `filter` when the list comprehension doesn't need one.

Comment: I truly love LC but if the end result is to filter out values, then `filter` conveys that much more clearly but thats just my opinion, funny my first though was to use LC but I saw that everyone was using them and I noted the OP wanted to filter things out, so I decided to use `filter` :)

Comment: As for the link, interesting, but I think Guido just hates lambda, I don't know why :(

Comment: Seems like list comprehensions are preferred over filter regardless of lambdas: "I think dropping filter() and map() is pretty uncontroversial; filter(P, S) is almost always written clearer as [x for x in S if P(x)]"

Comment: @F.J yeah but I noted this `Why drop lambda?` in the second paragraph and he mentioned somewhere, I think, that he regretted ever adding it to the language, to this day I still don't know why, when many languages are actually adding it ... I think Java and C# have it now, not sure.

Answer (score 7):

Use a list comprehension where the conditional checks for membership in a set:

```
>>> all_data = [['abc', 123], ['cde', 234], ['fgh', 345]]
>>> ids = ['abc', 'fgh']
>>> id_set = set(ids)
>>> [s for s in all_data if s[0] in id_set]
[['abc', 123], ['fgh', 345]]
```

Comment: If I have the same answer as you Raymond, that means i must be doing something right :)

Comment: @anijhaw: No, your answer is O(m·n), while Raymond's is O(n).

Comment: I meant to use a set I think I fat fingered it but thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 7):

Edited after the comment, I meant to use a set.
As Raymond suggests in his answer use a list comprehension :) with a set for ids.

```
all_data = [['abc', 123], ['cde', 234], ['fgh', 345]]
ids = set(['abc', 'fgh'])
filtered_data = [x for x in all_data if x[0] in ids]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should turn `all_data` into a dictionary, since you use it like one:

```
d = dict(all_data)
new_data = [(k, d[k]) for k in ids]
```

This will use the order given by `ids`, not the order given by `all_data`.

Comment: Maybe order is important to him?

Comment: @sblom: It might be important, though in that case it's unclear whether to use the order of `all_data` or the order of `ids`.  (Also note that you probably mean "important to *her*".)

Comment: definitely _her_. Sorry, @Lillian!

Answer (score 0):

Your second question isn't harder, just the proper way to structure your data from the beginning:

```
>>> all_data = {'abc': 123, 'cde': 234,'fgh': 345}  # a dict
>>> ids = {'abc', 'fgh'}  # a set
>>> {k:v for k,v in all_data.viewitems() if k in ids}
{'abc': 123, 'fgh': 345}
```

By the way, a nice fast way to get the matching keys is:

```
>>> all_data.viewkeys() & ids 
set(['abc', 'fgh'])
```